# Webcam support in Pidgin for Yahoo! protocol?

Tags: webcam, pidgin

Today I reinstalled Ubuntu and I'm using Yahoo! Messenger under Pidgin. I don't know if it supports video chat.

Does Pidgin have webcam support when connected to Yahoo!?

Answer (score 2):

This is something you can easily find using Google: [Pidgin FAQ](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#VoiceandVideoMicrophoneandWebcamSupport).